# Is there a design pattern regarding numerical combination

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns

I am looking for the name of a technique or design pattern, to get some documentation that would help my implementation. So this question isn't language related even though I'm implementing in C++.

Due to some limitations in an (old) API, I would like to store a combination of parameters in only 1 integer value.

I am thinking of using something similar to the buttons argument of the [VBA MsgBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/msgbox-function) (yeah I know, VBA, but hey I had to learn some a while ago... And the solution I thinking of is very close to that implementation)

My need is to have a series of parameters with various values.
For example:

> 1. A first param with a 0 or 1 value, that could be translated to true or false.
> 2. A 2nd parameter a 0 or 2 or 4, that could translate to a selection of a ternary,
> 3. And a third to 0 or 8 or 16 or 32 or 64, which would represent a parameter with 5
>    possible values
>
> I would then be able to sum them, and the result
> would become very easy to decode as any value would only match a
> unique set of sum, that I could translate both ways.
>
> For instance, I
> could save 35, which would be decoded as 32 + 2 + 1, so param1 = true,
> param2 = param2_value2 and param3 = param3_value4.
>
> 33 would translate to 32 + 0 + 1, the only change would be param2 = param2_value1

I have a working implementation of this, but I find it could be improved a lot, although I'm not sure how. I have much more parameters to save in my real use case, and some with much more possible values. My main concern over this implementation is that I would have to rework all the values if a new item would be added to any of the list.

I hope I'm being clear with my problem! I have spent quite some time searching for things such as "Numerical Combinatorics" and "sum of binary value to define several settings", learning about a lot of stuff but nothing helped me so far, and I'm pretty sure it's only a keyword issue there.

Answer (score 1):

For the most compact packing, you can use a mixed numeration representation.

First assume that your three parameters are mapped to the ranges `[0, 1]`, `[0, 2]` and `[0, 4]`. Then you can pack `"abc"`, where the "digits" have the respective weights `1`, `5` and `3.5=15` from right to left.

```
"abc" = 15.a + 5.b + c
```

For example, `"102" = 15.1 + 5.0 + 2 = 17`.

---

To retrieve the values, you apply integer division repeatedly.

```
17 = (17/15).15 + (17%15) = 1.15 + 2
2 = (2/5).5 + (2%5)       = 0.5  + 2
2 = (2/1).1 + (2%1)       = 2.1  + 0
```

---

As divisions are slow, it can be better to round the sizes of the ranges to the next power of `2`, i.e. `[0, 2] -> [0, 3]` and `[0, 5] -> [0, 7]`. The you get more classical bit field packing, as integrated in the C language.

---

If you want to later extend the set of values without compromising the existing coding, you have two options:

- reserving spare values in every field for future extensions;
- adding new fields past the highest weights to extend the range of some parameter. But this will make the handling much harder, will be inefficient and also susceptible to overflow.

E.g. you want to add a fourth value for the field `b`, then use an extra field `b'` with weight `30=2.3.5`, taking a binary value. Then the concatenation of `b'b` gives a field that supports `6=2.3` values, with the new representation `"b'abc"`.

Comment: But OP's main concern is "what if more values are needed later", not how to make it even more compact, right? (If it is more compact, it might be easier to allot a bit of space for yet unused values, but not sure if this really solves the problem.)

Comment: @tobias_k: maybe. Anyway, the explanation of the coding by the OP seems wrong.